# Parse Oracle XML for Visualization

Tags: xml, flowchart, peoplesoft

I am attempting to take equation logic (from Peoplesoft, for those who are familiar.  Specifically "Equation Engine") which was output from the system as XML and parse it so that I can eventually programmatically create a flowchart that visualizes the logic for that particular equation.  In the past I have used XMLSerializer within a C# desktop app, but that was when the XML structure could be mapped directly into a class.

In this case, there is branching if/then logic that I would like to capture, as well as variable assignment with mathematical operations included:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<EQUATION>
    <EQUATIONNAME>F5_ADJ_AWD_S</EQUATIONNAME>
    <ASSIGN>
        <GLOBAL>PER_CREDIT</GLOBAL>
        <GLOBAL>GLOBAL_AWARD</GLOBAL>
        <OPERATOR>/</OPERATOR>
        <VALUE>30</VALUE>
    </ASSIGN>
    <ASSIGN>
        <LOCAL>ORIGINAL_EFA_AY_VALUE</LOCAL>
        <COMMENT>Store local version of EFA AY value</COMMENT>
        <GLOBAL>GLOBAL_AWARD</GLOBAL>
    </ASSIGN>
    <ASSIGN>
        <GLOBAL>TEMP_VALUE</GLOBAL>
        <VALUE>0</VALUE>
    </ASSIGN>
    <IF>
        <GLOBAL>WORK_FIELD_CHAR_05</GLOBAL>
        <OPERATOR>=</OPERATOR>
        <STRING>SPRING</STRING>
        <THEN/>
        <COMMENT>Start of Spring section</COMMENT>
        <ASSIGN>
            <GLOBAL>STRM</GLOBAL>
            <STRING>2310</STRING>
            <COMMENT>In the spring, the global strm above will be the spring value, so this resets it to fall in order to grab the fall value</COMMENT>
        </ASSIGN>
        <CALL/>
        <EQTN>F1_SEL_BY_IT</EQTN>
        <ASSIGN>
            <GLOBAL>FALL_VALUE</GLOBAL>
            <GLOBAL>TEMP_VALUE</GLOBAL>
        </ASSIGN>
        <ASSIGN>
            <GLOBAL>COMBINED_UNIT_MAX_VALUE</GLOBAL>
            <COMMENT>Max value based on per credit times combined units, or remaining Spring eligible value when in Fall mode</COMMENT>
                <LOCAL>ORIGINAL_EFA_AY_VALUE</LOCAL>
                <COMMENT>AY Value</COMMENT>
                <OPERATOR>-</OPERATOR>
                <GLOBAL>FALL_VALUE</GLOBAL>
                <COMMENT>Fall Value</COMMENT>
        </ASSIGN>
        <ASSIGN>
            <GLOBAL>GLOBAL_AMT</GLOBAL>
            <GLOBAL>WORK_FIELD_NUM_01</GLOBAL>
            <COMMENT>Spring units</COMMENT>
            <OPERATOR>*</OPERATOR>
            <GLOBAL>PER_CREDIT</GLOBAL>
        </ASSIGN>
        <ELSE/>
        <COMMENT>Start of Fall section</COMMENT>
        <ASSIGN>
            <GLOBAL>FALL_VALUE</GLOBAL>
            <COMMENT>Move fall value from WFN4 into a different global so the same "Fall_value" variable can be used in both mode. Note: WFN4</COMMENT>
            <GLOBAL>WORK_FIELD_NUM_04</GLOBAL>
            <COMMENT>in spring mode contains the fall units, but in fall mode contains the fall item type value</COMMENT>
        </ASSIGN>
        <ASSIGN>
            <GLOBAL>COMBINED_UNIT_MAX_VALUE</GLOBAL>
            <COMMENT>Max value based on per credit times combined units, or remaining Spring eligible value when in Fall mode</COMMENT>
            <LOCAL>ORIGINAL_EFA_AY_VALUE</LOCAL>
            <COMMENT>Original Merit AY amt</COMMENT>
            <OPERATOR>-</OPERATOR>
            <PAREN>
                <GLOBAL>WORK_FIELD_NUM_01</GLOBAL>
                <COMMENT>Fall Units</COMMENT>
                <OPERATOR>*</OPERATOR>
                <GLOBAL>PER_CREDIT</GLOBAL>
            </PAREN>
        </ASSIGN>
        <ASSIGN>
            <GLOBAL>GLOBAL_AMT</GLOBAL>
            <VALUE>15</VALUE>
            <COMMENT>Default Term Units</COMMENT>
            <OPERATOR>*</OPERATOR>
            <GLOBAL>PER_CREDIT</GLOBAL>
        </ASSIGN>
    </IF>
    <COMMENT>End of separate Fall and Spring logic</COMMENT>
</EQUATION>
```

In the example above, the first "Assign" element is actually doing this:
global variable "PER_CREDIT" = global variable "GLOBAL_AWARD" / 30

Would XMLReader be a better approach, or is this type of XML not really something that can be converted in the way I am trying to do?

Edit: I should have mentioned, I was going to try to do this via C# (like windows form, or console, with the eventual goal of outputting a flowchart somehow) though I am also thinking python might be a better choice given the visualization goal

Comment: Can you add the expected result of the transformation for your XML example?

Comment: If I had to solve this task, I would think about preprocessing or a complete transformation using [xq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#xml-support), depending on how complex and nested the equations can get

Comment: there is a misleading wrong indention in the <ASSIGN> block for COMBINED_UNIT_MAX_VALUE

Comment: This is a strange XML format depending on position, e.g. the logic for "THEN" and "ELSE" is not within the <THEN> and <ELSE> tag. The argument for <CALL/> is listed as sibling. I guess it won't be easy to visualise this format cleanly

Comment: I think ideally the end result would be something like https://ibb.co/8g5SZxV
I am trying to find a way to convert this (problematic) "XML" output (which has issues, as you've pointed out) into something that I could put into code2flow (or, better yet, develop my own visualization tool so I am not limited to 50 nodes in the free version or 200 in the paid).  For the nesting, I wouldn't have it go down into the called equation (I would create a separate flow chart for the called one, later).  I'll take a look into xq like you suggested.  Perhaps I will have to scrub the output first, myself

Comment: in order to address the indentation issues, and maybe manually alter the then and else tags (by adding <THEN> and <ELSE> tags so they have their own section).  Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Maybe the [activity diagram](https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-legacy) from plant UML can help you

Comment: I did a little coding with this unusual XML to normalize it a little. I tested two different XML parsers and both showed the same behaviour: Inside the <IF>, all <ASSIGN> tags are combined into an array. As a result, the order is not stable. The </ELSE> moves to the end and the logic is no longer correct.
I am at a loss now :-/

Comment: @jpseng no worries, it was worth a shot, but I think the output as provided by the system clearly is too problematic.  I really appreciate you trying to figure this out for me!  Seriously, thank you very much

Comment: It was an exciting question that kept me busy. At least it was fun for me to try a bit